# NSKeyedArchiver default location and categories in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios5

1.where did i find default location of nskeyedarchiver?

2.
app.h

```
@interface uiview(extensions)
```

app.m

```
@implementation uiview(extensions)
```

what is the  use  of (extensions) like

```
@interface uiview(extensions)
```

in objective c

pls give me a solution....

2 questions

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Is this even one question or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app.h
>
> @interface uiview(extensions)
>
> app.m
>
> @implementation uiview(extensions)

This is called **Categories** in iOS. You can write your own methods and implementations to the existing class. You can know more about this from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)

Regarding KeyedArchiver, you can write the archived object to any place like Documents or any other folders of your choice. For more info, see [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html)